# how to configure routes group in dialogflow cx

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I've a problem with the routes group in DialogflowCX.
I've created the routes group in the Manage tab but i can't use them in the flow or single pages, why? Both in the page and in the flow, there isn't a Routes Group section but only the Routes section. How can I use Routes group in the flow or pages?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The route groups may be called when the page is active. Flow-level routes are routes that are applied to a flow[1] these handlers with an intent requirement in scope for all pages in the flow or in scope for the flow start page. Page-level routes are routes that are applied to a page[2] these handlers with an intent or condition requirement in scope when specific pages are active.

Said this, you can go to the page view in the visual console and click “Add route type”, flag route groups and add the group you created with the `+` button.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route-flow
[2]https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#route-page